# W3C validator and HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, w3c-validation

I'm currently having trouble with the W3C markup validation service https://validator.w3.org and the use of HTTPS. When I type in there the website address with `https` I get the following response:

> Sorry! This document cannot be checked.

Together with an error 500 saying that it can't connect to the site. Also, on the website page I have one link which carries the person into the validation and shows the site has been validated. When clicking the link without HTTPS everything works, but with HTTPS I get one message

> Sorry! This document cannot be checked. No Referer header found!

which I believe is because the secure connection doesn't send the referer header right?

Now, how can I use HTTPS and avoid these problems with the validation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please always directly use https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (the current **W3C HTML Checker**) instead of https://validator.w3.org/ (the legacy W3C Markup Validator).

The HTML Checker is able to check documents at `https` URLS just fine. So If you find a `https` site that it doesn’t work with as expected, then that’s likely a bug I need to fix. (I maintain the checker, and [recently updated it to get HTTPS support using HTTP Components HttpClient 4.4](https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/ce45db603aa77fa5809044e4e1d82c9431fd8b7f) —the latest Apache HTTP client library—including full support for HTTPS sites that use SNI.

---

**A note about which W3C tool to use for checking HTML documents**

On the W3C backend, when you use the https://validator.w3.org/ legacy Markup Validator to check documents with `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctypes, it just hands off the request to the same backend that directly drives the  https://validator.w3.org/nu/ HTML Checker. But the HTML Checker has a UI with more features, and using it from https://validator.w3.org/nu/ is faster.

We (the W3C) plan to swap those two around eventually—that is, move the current HTML Checker to https://validator.w3.org/ and move the legacy Markup Validator to `https://validator.w3.org/legacy/` or some such—but it will be a while yet before that happens. So in the mean time, as I said, I suggest always just doing all your HTML checking from the https://validator.w3.org/nu/ site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sideshowbarker! I didn't know there was a new version. The new version really is able to check even with https! Just one question: the old validator returned a message like "This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!" telling the document passed the validation. On the new one this kind of message didn't show up. This is something that won't exist anymore or will be implemented in the future? Also, will be some "validation icon" as in the legacy version, which allowed one to see the validation of the page when clicking it? Thanks very much again!

Comment: The lack of a “This document was successfully checked as…” message is intentional. I have a strong rationale for omitting that; some people disagree, but  I don’t plan for the checker to ever emit that kind of message in the way the legacy markup validator does. The same is true for the “validator icon”: we (the W3C) have no plans to provide any “this is valid” icons from the HTML checker any longer. https://about.validator.nu/#no-badge explains some of the reasons why.

Comment: The omission of those two (mis)features I wrote about above is one reason why we named the tool *HTML Checker* instead of *Validator*; it’s not a validator—it is instead just [a tool to help you catch mistakes you might otherwise miss](https://validator.w3.org/nu/about.html#why-validate). So, HTML validation is dead, long live HTML checking!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the W3C NU validator, so the `"referer"` value is not processed fully. :-/

I.e. the code for their badge `<a target="_blank" href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer"><img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10" alt="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" title="Valid XHTML 1.0 Transitional" style="height: 31px; width: 88px;" /></a>`
does not validate my nested sub-page, but just the root-page of the whole web-site instead, on click on the badge, in a footer of the deep sub-page. Sad. :-/

And the same for the alternative parameterized ...`/check?uri=referer"` URL, still the same issue. :-/

Comment: They do mention it in `/check?uri=referer does not work - or - the validator says it does not support my "undefined" URL scheme`

on https://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-referer, but my URL is not httpS, just the simple plain http. And I use Chrome: 86.0.4240.111, 64b.

Comment: And the insertion of the static/absolute URL to the page (as a value to the URI-parameter, instead of the general relative "referer"), explicitly, is not a real solution: The same code snippet should behave differently for each single page, relatively to it.